# Do empty stacks automatically have a null value?

Tags: java, null, stack

I'm quite new to java. So I've got some code that is supposed to add files to a stack and compare the stack contents with an existing reference. Here's the class that should create the stack:

```java
public class ArrayStack<T> implements ArrayStackADT<T> {

    private T[] stack;
    private int top;
    
    // constructor, passes default capacity
    public ArrayStack() {
        top = -1;
        stack = (T[]) new Object[14];
    }
    
    // constructor, initializes capacity to stack and top
    public ArrayStack(int initialCapacity) {
        top = -1;
        stack = (T[])new Object[initialCapacity];
    }
}
```

and here is the code that calls the stack:

```java
public static void main(String[] args){
    StartSearch path = new StartSearch(args[0]);
    int distance = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    ArrayStack stack = new ArrayStack();    // creates empty stack
    MapCell cell = path.targetMap.getStart();    // gets starting cell
    stack.push(cell);   // pushes starting cell to stack
}
```

Not sure if I showed enough code, so please let me know if I didn't. I had some push and pop methods to insert and remove stack items, and for each push/pop they'd print "push" + the value:

```
if (dataItem instanceof MapCell) {
    sequence += "push" + ((MapCell)dataItem).getIdentifier();
}
else {
    sequence += "push" + dataItem.toString();
}
```

For some reason though, when I go to print sequence later, it outputs this:

```
nullpush0push2push3
```

Instead of what I need it to output:

```
push0push2push3
```

Do empty stacks automatically have a null value or something? how do I get rid of the null value at the beginning?

Comment: if there really was a `null` value at the beginning, it would a) write `pushnull` and b) not do that at all but throw a `NullPointerException` instead because you call a method on `dataItem` which would be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It hasn’t got anything to do with your stack class. It’s how you initialize your `String` variable. Or perhaps forgot to initialize it? To demonstrate:

```
    String sequence = null;
    sequence += "push1";
    System.out.println(sequence);
```

Output is:

> nullpush1

Instead initialize `sequence` to the empty string:

```
    String sequence = "";
```

> push1

Or use a `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`:

```
    StringBuilder sequence = new StringBuilder();
    sequence.append("push1");
    System.out.println(sequence);
```

Output is identical:

> push1